# fileinput.js InitialPreview tries to show the PDF into <img tag

Tags: file-io

I have multiples fileinputs in a page and populate the initialPreview on the load passing the files. But for PDF I am getting the initialPreview trying to load the PDF into img tag as result they do not show
What can be the problem?
When selecting a PDF manually with the "browse" button is previewing the PDF well but not when initialPreview.

```
$(".fileUpload :input").each(function(){
    var inputElement = $( this );
    inputElement.fileinput({
    showUpload: false,
    showCaption: false,
    fileType: "any",
    previewFileIcon: "",
    initialPreviewAsData: true,
    initialPreview: [
    inputElement.parent().parent().attr('data-url') // Here is the pdf. For example: ../../public/images/6daebfaa533798aabc7bbd410361dd1a.pdf
    ],
    autoReplace: true,
    maxFileCount: 1,
    overwriteInitial: true,
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to indicate the file extencion for every file we want to show

```
initialPreviewConfig: [
   {type: inputElement.parent().parent().attr('data-format')},
]
```